# Ayuda con switch y getopt

Tags: c++, stdin

Estoy tratando de leer los argumentos en el main con este codigo, lo que necesito es que, cuando los argumentos sean `-v` entonces `a = 10` guarde esto y cuando sean `-g` pase `flag a true`, pero cuando lo corro con -g me manda *"archivo: unknown option -- g"*

```
string val;
string name;
bool flag=false;
int c;
while((c=getopt(argc,argv,"vg:")) != -1){
  string a;
  bool b;
  int va;
  switch(c){
  case 'v':
    b=false;
    a=optarg;      
    for (int i=0;i<a.length();i++){
       if(a[i]!='='&& b==false)
         {
          name+=a[i];
         }
      if(a[i]!='='&& b==true)
        {
         val+=a[i];
        }
     if(a[i]=='=')
        {
         b=true;
        }
     }

    va=atoi(val.c_str());
    calc->addVal(name,va);
    name.clear();
    val.clear();
    a.clear();
    break;

 case 'g':

   flag=true;
   cout<<flag<<endl;
   break;


  }
}
```

Comment: pones -v o solo v?

Comment: -v asi ./archivo.exe -v a=10

Comment: proba sin el guion

Comment: no entra a ninguno de los 2 si no le pongo el -

Comment: no te falta una coma?, prueba con `/archivo.exe -v,a=10`

Comment: No seguia igual, de alguna forma se arreglo el problema de que pasara al g y cambiara el booleano pero ahora me manda archivo: unknown option -- g   cuando lo uso con ./archivo.exe -g

Comment: ahora si no te reconoce g

Answer (score 0):

#### Solución:

Se cambia el patrón `vg:`...

```
while((c=getopt(argc,argv,"vg:")) != -1){
```

... por `gv:`, el doble punto (`:`) es `optarg`, es decir `a=10`, viene luego de la `v`:

```
while((c=getopt(argc,argv,"gv:")) != -1){
```

Ejemplo de ejecución del programa:

```
./programa -gv "a = 10"
```

*Nota: Es importante poner `a = 10` entre comillas porque interfiere con espacios. También se puede `a=10` pero sin las comillas.*

#### Algunos detalles extras:

Para incluir `getopt`:

```
#include <getopt.h>
```

Clase `calc` con constructor y función `addVal`:

```
class calc {
    public:
        string name;
        int va;
        calc(){
            this->name = "";
            this->va = 0;
        }
        void addVal(string name,int va){
            this->name = name;
            this->va = va;
        }
};
```

Declarando un nuevo `calc`, en mi caso lo llamo `calcu`:

```
struct calc* calcu = new calc();
```

Pasando cada caso en funciones diferentes `g` y `v`:

```
case 'g':g(&flag);break;
case 'v':v(calcu);break;
```

#### Código completo

```
#include <iostream>
#include <getopt.h>

using namespace std;

class calc {
    public:
        string name;
        int va;
        calc(){
            this->name = "";
            this->va = 0;
        }
        void addVal(string name,int va){
            this->name = name;
            this->va = va;
        }
};
void g(bool* flag){
    *flag=true;
}
void v(struct calc* calcu){
    string name;
    string val="";
    string a = optarg;
    int va = 0;
    bool b = false;
    for (int i=0;i<(int)a.length();i++){
        if(a[i]!='='&& b==false)
        {
            name+=a[i];
        }
        if(a[i]!='='&& b==true)
        {
            val+=a[i];
        }
        if(a[i]=='=')
        {
            b=true;
        }
    }
    va=atoi(val.c_str());
    calcu->addVal(name,va);
}
int main(int argc,char** argv){
    bool flag=false;
    int c;
    struct calc* calcu = new calc();
    while((c=getopt(argc,argv,"gv:")) != -1){
        switch(c){
            case 'g':g(&flag);break;
            case 'v':v(calcu);break;
        }
    }
    cout<<"g: flag: "<<flag<<endl;
    cout<<"v: name: \""<< calcu->name <<"\", va: "<< calcu->va <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

#### Salida del programa

```
g: flag: 1
v: name: "a ", va: 10
```

Hay que tener en cuenta que al pasar `"a = 10"` con el espacio entre `a` y el `=`, el nombre será `"a "` en vez de `"a"`.